# How to remove "¼" and "½" from a string

Tags: java

I need to remove the characters '¼' and '½' from a string in Java. How can I do that?

I do not have control over the request, I have to accept what the input comes as. Basically the request string has the characters '¼' and '½', and I need to replace these with the empty string.

I tried putting it in a list and it did not work:

invalidChars.add('½');

and then search through this. Jenkins complains: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 [INFO] 2 errors

Comment: Have you tried `input.replaceAll("1/2", "½")`?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to work around broken character encodings.  You should fix your system to use UTF8.

Comment: Are you saying the string should display 1/2 and 1/4 but instead it displays empty strings?

Comment: SLaks: how can you possibly infer that with such little information from the original post?

Comment: sigh. i stand corrected. you must have mind reading skills.

Comment: `myString.replaceAll("[\xBC\xBD]", "")`

Comment: Yes, you are saving source code in something like ISO 8859-1 whereas Jenkins is configured with UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you can write:

```
input = input.replace("\u00BC", "").replace("\u00BD", "");
```

. . . but I'm a bit suspicious of your use-case. It seems like this won't fix whatever the *real* problem is.

Comment: This is a quite inefficient way about it because it will both search twice and allocate the whole request string twice.  A regex character class is a much better choice.

Comment: but it's simpler and who cares about efficiency unless the strings are huge.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Searching twice for a substring, vs. searching once for a regex character-class -- to decide which is more efficient, you'd have to test. (Regexes aren't magical, y'know. `"[\u00BC\u00BD]"` would still have to compare each character of the input-string to both possible values.) Allocating the string twice -- well, the usual regex way is `input.replaceAll("[\u00BC\u00BD]", "")`, which has to create a `Pattern` and a `Matcher` every time, as well as the result-string. *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* Overall, since my approach involves copying the entire string twice, it might well perform slightly worse on very large strings, but it's hard to be sure: the number of copies differs only by a small constant factor, and the performance of linear-regex-search vs. substring-search differs by at *least* that, so it's impossible to decide *a priori* which one would end up being faster.

Comment: If we're discussing performance, naturally I assume non-trivial string length. Going over it twice is without doubt less efficient due to cache misses. Also, I assume precompiled Regex. I have tested such things before and the difference is real.

Comment: @jasons It's one method call against two and less characters. It obviously scales dramatically better. I wonder how it's more complex. As for performance, if it comes free with The right way to do it, rejecting it is just shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: You say "I assume non-trivial string length" and "I assume precompiled Regex" as though we were discussing this in the abstract, rather than discussing an actual real-world use case -- one where you've made claims with terms like "quite inefficient" and "much better choice". The fact is, in most cases it's better to write code in the simplest, clearest way than to write it in the most efficient way, because in most cases the difference in simplicity and clarity is greater than the difference in efficiency.

Comment: My way *is* simple and clear. If you disagree, that's just your opinion against mine.

Comment: It is one method call in your code. I am replying to the claim that Regex code is more complex.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: This whole thing is just opinion. You have no evidence to support your assumptions about efficiency. Maybe this code is called in a very tight loop over a very large number of very small strings, in which case my version will be more efficient than yours.

Comment: As for total method calls executed, did you really inspect both implementations? String#replace is no one-liner, either.

Comment: It is about processing a *request*. It is not a tight loop, but even if it was, I don't know where you get the assumption that regexes are inefficient.

Comment: I have just completed the measurements. On an 800-char string, your `replace` is 50% slower than `replaceAll`, which means even when I compile the regex each time, it still beats your solution by a wide margin on a sub-1K string.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Re: "String#replace is no one-liner, either": Oh, absolutely. Neither one is native code. And I'm really not arguing against regexes; I use them often, and considered using them for this answer, before deciding that `replace` would be simpler and easier for the OP. Rather, I'm arguing against the claims in your initial comment ("quite inefficient", "much better choice").

Comment: The strongest case I have against replace is that it scales badly with each futher char to delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the string is a variable you can do this

```
public void asciiReplacer(String str)
{
String[]tmp= str.split(" ");
 for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++){
  if(temp[i].equals((char)189)
      temp[i] = " ";
  if(temp[i].equals((char)188)
      temp[i] = " ";
  System.out.println(temp[i]+"\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning a char to a String? Now how are you comparing a String to a char with equals?

Comment: Thanks guys, seems like Lucarnosky's idea works but I need to see once I put it in the svn and Jenkins builds it, then the issue appears.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked and Jenkins built it successfully.