# Regex pattern to convert comma separated string to dot separated one

Tags: java, regex

I want to convert an long array values to a specific format of string.

for e.g. longArray = {0,1,2,3} to be converted as string 0.1.2.3

I can do Arrays.toString(longArray) which will return [0, 1, 2, 3].

Now this string [0,1,2,3] has to be converted into 0.1.2.3

I have used this code which works but would like to see if this code can be improved

```
String convertedString = Arrays.toString(longArray).replaceAll(",",".").replaceAll("[\\[,\\],\\s]", "");
```

I have to mention that i am on Java 7 so can't use any Java 8 features like streams
Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Most languages have a join function. Use `.` as the character. If java doesn't, just loop through the array.. make your own string.

Comment: concision-wise, given it's Java, that seems to be as good as it gets (if you don't want to include 3rd party libraries), though you could use a static import

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: join array of primitives with separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425623/java-join-array-of-primitives-with-separator)

Comment: The regex character class `[]` doesn't use comma to separate characters. A character class matching `a` and `b` would be `[ab]`, not `[a,b]`. Also, super minor improvement, the second `replaceAll` call shortens the text, so flipping the order will leave fewer characters for the other `replaceAll` call to process: `.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\s]+", "").replaceAll(",",".")` (see [this comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359325/removing-all-fraction-symbols-like-%c2%bc-and-%c2%bd-from-a-string/43359401#comment73794375_43359401) about the `+` I added).

Comment: `Arrays.toString(longArray).replace(",  ", ".").replaceFirst(".(.*).", "$1");`

Comment: @ctwheels i checked with the common lang's array utils and string utils...but that call is not performant..it is taking 40 ms in compared to my native solution which is taking around 10ms

Comment: @Andreas thanks switching the order has increased the performance from 10ms to 3ms

Answer (score 1):

```
    long[] longArray = {0,1,2,3};
    String s = LongStream.of(longArray)
            .mapToObj(Long::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("."));
```

Array of longs to stream of longs, every long mapped to a String with `Long.toString(long)` and then joined with a delimiter `.`.

*Originally I has `String::valueOf` instead of `Long.toString`. Thanks to @Andreas for a slightly better style.*

Comment: @Andreas Or `Long::toString(long)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not much shorter, but I think the regular expressions make it look more elegant:

```
String convertedString = Arrays.toString(longArray)
.replaceAll("^.|.$", "");
.replaceAll("[^0-9]+",".")
```

1. Remove first and last character.
2. Replace all non-numeric **strings** with dots.

Comment: seems almost same as my proposed solution...any performance improvement with your solution by using the negate operator ?

Comment: You do know that `.` does match a period, right? It matches *any* character, so it would be safer to escape it, i.e. `"^\\.|\\.$"`

Comment: Just the use of the `+`, to include all the strings, not only individual characters

Comment: @Andreas I intentionally want to remove the first and the last characters